# How to pass data of sent SMS message using PendingIntent to BroadcastReciever?

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I want to pass some data to `BroadcastReceiver` when sending a lot of SMS to indicate which message is sent/delivered.

I tried to use standard `PendingIntent` with different flags but got wrong results (BroadcastReceiver always get first/last extras of an intent). Does anyone know how to pass data to `BroadcastReceiver` while sending SMS message using `SmsManager`?

Function that sends SMS:

```
private void sendSMS(SmsRequest _smsRequest) {

        Intent sentInt = new Intent(SmsNotificationSending.SENT);
        sentInt.putExtra("SMS_ID", _smsRequest.getmId());

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sentInt, 0);

        Intent delivInt = new Intent(SmsNotificationSending.DELIVERED);
        delivInt.putExtra("SMS_ID", _smsRequest.getmId());

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, delivInt, 0);

        registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager
                .getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(1)
                .sendTextMessage(_smsRequest.getmRecipientNumber(),
                        null,
                        _smsRequest.getmMessage(),
                        sentPI,
                        deliveredPI);
    }
```

My `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class DeliveryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Log.d("sms", "Broadcast received: " + intent.getAction());
                Log.d("sms" ,"Sms was delivered" + intent.getIntExtra("SMS_ID", -1));
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Log.d("sms" ,"Sms was not delivered");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

`sendSms()` calling many times one by one and in logs I'm getting many received broadcasts as should, but only with the first `SMS_ID` of SMS message.
Please, help me!

Comment: That doesn't seem possible. You create each `PendingIntent` with a different ACTION, and that ACTION is some random number (`Long` value). Then, you register a receiver that should be called when the ACTION is a fixed string `SENT` or `DELIVERED`, whatever those are. As these things don't match, your `BroadcastReceiver` shouldn't ever be called!

Comment: @DavidWasser I'm sorry, I accidentally posted code where I didn't change that thing , but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't do what you want:

```
    Intent sentInt = new Intent(SmsNotificationSending.SENT);
    sentInt.putExtra("SMS_ID", _smsRequest.getmId());
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sentInt, 0);

    Intent delivInt = new Intent(SmsNotificationSending.DELIVERED);
    delivInt.putExtra("SMS_ID", _smsRequest.getmId());
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, delivInt, 0);
```

The problem is that this code reuses the same `PendingIntent` every time (which has the first SMS_ID in the extras).

What you need to do is create a new `PendingIntent` every time this code is executed. In order to do that you need to do one (or more) of the following:

- Use a different `requestCode` (2nd parameter) in the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` each time
- Use a different ACTION in the `Intent` every time (you can do this by including the SMS_ID in the ACTION when you instantiate the `Intent` with `new Intent(...)`

This will ensure that unique `PendingIntent`s are created each time and that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a little bit faster than me, I just started writing the answer by myself because I solved this issue 2 month ago :D